# Google asks for location permission declaration for new android app release

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I want to deploy new version of android application to play store. And although I removed location permissions from my manifest file and they are not listed in release details I am getting this error message: `Your background location permission declaration needs to be updated.` Am I missing something? How do I fix this?

Comment: I found out what is problem. New apk does not have Location permission listed, but current active apk has it. So I cannot create new release until I request Location permission for the current release. Can I delete active release somehow?

Comment: You just have to complete the App Permissions section in your [play console](https://play.google.com/console).

Comment: But I cannot submit Location permission request because my app does not use location. And in request you need to explain why you need it and attach video, and I cant do that because I don't use location.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing. First had location permissions, then removed them, but google play still forces me to update my location permissions.

Comment: HOW complete the "App Permissions section?"  I don't see that anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

[image: Screen 3]

I was able to submit permission declaration in that way as I uploaded screens.

Comment: add some descriptions as well

Comment: For some reason I was not able to fill out the "Sensitive app permissions" form. Since the app was still a (very old) draft version I deleted the app and created it again, this time Google did not need the location permission declaration.